# Port Security Configuration

Tags: networking, security

I am new to networking and am trying to understand different methods to secure switch ports.  I have noticed that with Cisco switches for instance, you can use switch port-security and specify the mac address associated to that port.  However, mac addresses can be manually changed at OS level, so what is the use of such action?

Comment: A hostile user would have to know which MAC addresses you have allowed on your network.  This isn't trivial information to gather and would require access to your network, in order to gather it.  There are many reasons for limiting a certain MAC address to a specific port.  What threats are you attempting to prevent specifically?  Please edit your question to avoid the unnecessary broadness of your question as its currently written.

Comment: @Ramhound  You are absolutely right, securing switch ports would definitely count as a basic step among many other steps that one needs to take in securing the network in general and my apologies if my question was not clear...what I am mostly interested in understanding is how to prevent an internal threat, where an intruder would somehow get hold of the victim's MAC address.  Are there any methods for preventing such an intruder from acting as victim's computer?

Comment: Don’t allow personal devices in the network and lock down any machine in such a way the MAC address cannot be changed.